# SSH: In private network how to access the remote machine from source machine without using ssh public key

Tags: linux, ssh, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have AWS codebuild setup where want to access the EC2 ubuntu instance both are in same VPC and private subnet. Want to execute the command from codebuild to instance using SSH but getting below error, while trying to execute the command on the remote instance:

```
$ ssh -o 'PubkeyAuthentication no' ubuntu@X.X.X.X uname
Host key verification failed.
```

I also tried to create the .pem file and pasted the public key to the new pem file, changed its permission and used that. But no success.

```
$ssh -i "remote-instance.pem" ubuntu@X.X.X.X uname
Host key verification failed.
```

Is it possible to achieve the same with some options?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As you know the first time you `ssh` to a remote host it asks you whether you'd like to store the **remote host key** to `~/.ssh/known_hosts`. Every time you access the remote host afterwards `ssh` verifies received **host key** against `~/.ssh/known_hosts`.

However when `ssh` runs in *CodeBuild* or some other non-interactive setup it can't ask whether to accept the remote key (because there's no one to ask in a non-interactive session) and to be on the safe side it fails with **Host key verification failed**

You've got two options how to fix it:

1. *More secure* is to provide the Ubuntu server's host key to your CodeBuild and store it to a `known_hosts` file where `ssh` can verify it. Make sure it's in the right path with the correct ownership and permissions.
2. *Less secure* is to disable the check:

   ```
   ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no {your-ubuntu-server}
   ```

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you @MLu for the response, I tried StrictHostKeyChecking option before but not with 'PubkeyAuthentication'. I still get error saying 'ubuntu@X.X.X.X: Permission denied (publickey).' when executes the command:

ssh -o PubkeyAuthentication=no -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no ubuntu@X.X.X.X uname

Comment: I have also tried the 1st way and created the .pem file and pasted the public key and tried to ssh to the ubuntu server. But it was again throwing the error.
As my codebuild and ubuntu machine is on the same private network so disabling the ssh secure check should be fine to me.

Comment: Sounds like you have multiple issue here, the 'Host key verification failed' error will be resolved with the steps above, but then you are saying you now have a 'Permission denied (publickey)', this could be for a number of reasons, but relates specifically to your SSH key itself.  So double check you are using the right keys, that your key files are protected correctly (e.g. chmod 600 etc), if you use "ssh -v" it will provide more diagnostics as to what is happening.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMoore, I tried below command and it worked:

ssh -v -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i "instance.pem" ubuntu@X.X.X.X

Comment: Try sshing into it once manually, confirming the prompt, and from then on it should work without disabling an important security check.

Comment: @Shadur except that the OP has an ephemeral short lived ci/cd environment where you can’t do anything manually. That’s the whole point of this discussion ;)

Answer (score 1):

You do want PubkeyAuthentication which will be attempted by default, so do not specify "-o PubkeyAuthentication=no".  The pem file referenced by "-i" should be the private key, not the public key.  The public key will already be in place on your ubuntu server.

Comment: You still need "-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no" as well.

Comment: Thanks @sean, You are right.